# How to send ZPL code to printer to print labels or how to print labels from ASP NET CORE BLAZOR?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl

Working on a project I need to print barcode labels from ASP NET Core with Blazor on a Zebra printer

I have already researched everywhere and found that it can be done with JSPrintManager, but you have to pay to use it.

My questions are:

Since the printer uses ZPL code, how to send ZPL code to the printer connected on the USB client side, is there any method, TCP, method or library?

Is it possible to print in some other way without using ZPL code?

```
For example, having a list of products and pressing a button that prints the labels with their barcode and product description directly

either

Let it load a preview and then print the eqtieutas
```

Comment: Could you please share your `code snippet` or implementation details what you are trying to implement or having trouble with?